# What is this error in ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM Project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I Create new Project ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM and Replace References for
using ASP.NET MVC 3 ***Source code***

but When I run project again, get this exception:

> [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection
>   cannot be cast to
>   [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection.
>   Type A originates from
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Razor,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in
>   the context 'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.
>   Type B originates from
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Razor,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' in the context
>   'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\2505c7ee\369315c5\assembly\dl3\f7bae428\d03eeed8_85bbcb01\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.DLL'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.

Source Error:

```
Line 106:        internal static RazorWebSectionGroup GetRazorSection(string virtualPath) {
Line 107:            // Get the individual sections (we can only use GetSection in medium trust) and then reconstruct the section group
Line 108:            return new RazorWebSectionGroup() {
Line 109:                Host = (HostSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection(HostSection.SectionName, virtualPath),
Line 110:                Pages = (RazorPagesSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection(RazorPagesSection.SectionName, virtualPath)
```

> Source File:
>   E:\GreenTour\webpages\src\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\WebRazorHostFactory.cs
>   Line: 108

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This error means that part of your application is being compiled using your own copy of the source code as a reference while at runtime its finding the reference assemblies in the GAC. Make sure you remove all references to the GACed version of MVC 3 assemblies. This includes a number of things in your web.config files that use this public key token: 31bf3856ad364e35.

Answer (score 13):

I just came across the same problem whilst upgrading my app,  the problem was in the web.config file located in the views directory,  I blindly copied this over from the old app (my bad).

My solution ,  create a new MVC 4 app  and copy the web.config from the views directory to your app thats having the problem.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks - your comment "web.config file located in the views directory" just gave me a "ah ha!" moment.

Comment: This. I forget that there are other web.config files floating around in the Views directory (and sub-directories).

Comment: Totally forgot about the other web.configs. I was able to just change the version numbers, rather than creating a new app and copying that. But YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Although the above thread was useful.  I could not get things working until I created a 'dummy' 'basic' MVC 4 application and then compared the web.configs to find any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this not by removing all references to assemblies with the public key of 31bf3856ad364e35 as this covers a lot of irrelevant assemblies.

Instead it should be fixed by updating all configuration references

- System.Web.Mvc to 4
- System.Web.WebPages to 2
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor to 2

Be sure to update all the web.configs, including the ones in View directories.