# Installed MVC 4 Beta, now my MVC 3 projects throw an error when I rebuild all

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I just installed MVC 4 Beta, and now my MVC 3 projects (that I haven't converted yet to 4) are throwing an error when I rebuild all:

`Error  18  [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.`

Has anyone come across this yet? Thanks!

Comment: Related posts - [What is this error in ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4781586/465053) & [aspnet_regiis -i gives “webengine4.dll” error after installing MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9444831/465053)

Answer (score 59):

I've spent the entire day trying to fix this, and after an afternoon systematically ripping EVERYTHING out of my project except one basic view and one basic controller it was still throwing this error.  So I started deleting other stuff and found there was a rogue Web.Config file in my Views folder that had MVC 3 stuff in it.

Search your project for other Web.Config files!!!

Comment: Just to augment this - this can happen even when the offending web.config is in another Area of the project.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+T in ReSharper let me know where all my web.configs were, thanks for this!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, and was able to solve it as follows:

- Remove the assembly `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` from the project references.
- Press Save All on the solution
- Add the assembly again, make sure you select version 1.0.0.0. Select True for Specific Version in the reference properties.

Answer (score 4):

I got an solution for this:

You need to add this to your mvc 3 web.config:

```
    <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />

        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />

        <!-- Your namespace here -->
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

And also copy the binfiles from

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies
```

to your project binfolder

If you need deploy your mvc 4 project on a server that you dont have installed mvc 4 on you need to the same but change version from 1.0.0.0 to 2.0.0.0 in the section part.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm on a team at work. If I commit this to SVN, and they get latest with this in their web.config, and they DON'T have MVC 4 installed, will this throw an error?  I could always give this a try and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: No you should be fine! It dont change anything it just specifies it on web.config level

Answer (score 3):

The steps to fix this issue

1. First find all web.config files in whole project
2. In all web.config file, find the given 'cannot be cast' error code and change version 2.0.0.0 in configSections of  all web.config files
   `System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection`
3. again if the error comes then find that error code and change the version 2.0.0.0 in all web.config files. repeat the process until fix the version related issues.

Answer (score 1):

When you install MVC4, your mvc3 projects will point to system.web.webpages ver 2.0..

For you MVC3 projects, Remove the reference to system.web.webpages ver 2.0.. and add a reference back to system.web.webpages ver 1.0..

Recompile and redeploy and it should work again...

Not sure why it does that, but it's still a beta install

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else runs into this same problem.  It looks like there are a few different things that can cause this particular error.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4786513) is the best description of what is causing the error that I've found.  In my specific case, I added a reference to a library via NuGet, and it looks as if a specific reference to System.Web.WebPages was added to my project.  I removed this reference, rebuilt, and everything was good to go.

Good luck to others with similar problems!

Comment: I've had similar error, because ServiceStack NuGet package have replaced WebPages 2.0 reference with WebPages 1.0 one.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the references to System.Web.WebPages is 2.0.0.0 in **root/Web.config** and **root/Views/Web.config**

If every thing is pointing to version 2 then verify if you have the directory "**_bin_deployableAssemblies**".

If you have it, then right click on your project and choose the option "**Add Deployable Dependencies...**" then check MVC and Razor options to update your DLLs.

Comment: The 'Add Deployable Dependencies' link has been removed on VS2012.

Answer (score 1):

Might help someone:

1. Added correct version of DLL conlfic between razor 1.0 and 2.0
2. Modified the web.config file where it says 3.0 to 4.0 and 1.0 to 2.0 only for MVC and razor
3. Another web.config hidden under view that also need to be modified.

Above three steps helped to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem it's that you may have another web.config in the Views directory that have recerences pointing to the old asemblies. When the project loads, It tries to load both versions and then fails.

Try to also correct the versions on the "View's" web.config.

For the oncoming, like me.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you may have to update some of the assembly data in your web.config.

Comment: I'd like to keep my MVC 3.0 web configs as they are. Is this possible? Maybe not.

Comment: If you do change them, just make sure you have a backup. It seems to me that there are new versions of those assemblies and your project is registering "the wrong version" according to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It looks Like We need to change the version number, if we upgrade to mvc4 from mvc3.

I just changed the webconfig, which is in Views Folder.... Need to change the version number

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>


 <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=**4**.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=**4**.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=**4**.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=**4**.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```