# aspnet_regiis -i gives "webengine4.dll" error after installing MVC 4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, aspnet-regiis.exe

I recently installed MVC 4 Beta, and, when I hit F5 for any of my MVC 4 projects I get the error below.  Also, if I run `aspnet_regiis -i`, I get the same screenshot.

Is there a way to repair just this one dll?  Or, should I wipe out everything .NET- and MVC-related on my machine, then re-install .NET + MVC 4?  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What OS? Did you uninstall MVC 4 Preview first?

Comment: @KMoraz - that did it. thanks! can u put it as a response so I can mark it as Answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply official Microsoft [Update for the .NET Framework 4 (KB2468871)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871)

[Download link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3556)

Comment: I might even try this as a fix for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384421/installed-mvc-4-beta-now-my-mvc-3-projects-throw-an-error-when-i-rebuild-all. we'll see! thanks.